# When do the in-world resources respawn?

Tags: fantasy-life

In Fantasy Life you can wander around and gather the resources from the open world depending on which lives you have training in. These are things like gathering herbs, picking up ore, mining for said ore, fishing, picking up eggs... the list goes on.

How often do these resource points respawn? I thought initially one in-game day but I am now seeing things respawning quite a bit more often than that but not in any timeframe I can so far nail down.

Answer (score 5):

Some people say they respawn after sleeping for anywhere between 1 and 3 days, this may be true but there is a (sometimes) easier way to make things respawn.

For the normal ores and trees and herbs and such, simply going two loading screens away from the area you were harvesting in and coming back to it will cause them to respawn.
This does not work with the rare/special resources like rare fish and wingstones however.

Comment: Hmm Distance away would seem to explain it better as I do not normally sleep and can harvest them multiple times per day.

Comment: My vote is also two loading screens. Games that don't require sleep don't typically require it to respawn stuff.

Answer (score 1):

From experience and a book on Al Maajik library, Wingstones, Lordfishs, Great Trees and Boss Spawns usually respawn after 3 sleep days/sleep cycles. The bed on Mount Snowpeak only gives the rest option, and if I recall correctly it takes 2 rests for one sleep cycle - so, 6 rests for the Great Fir Tree or the Dino boss at the top ;)

One edit here: "sleep cycles" considering days - so if you just keep playing and pass 3 days, "boss things" will respawn the same way if you slept, so technically Reafexus is correct.

Other than that, keep with previous answer: 2 loading screens away and back should spawn everything back.