# Do the Forest Lordfish and other rare gatherables respawn?

Tags: fantasy-life

In *Fantasy Life* I caught the Forest Lordfish before getting the challenge to catch it. Consequently, the challenge is unfulfilled. Does it and other rare gatherables like it eventually respawn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed it does. To start with this question, we must ask what is the `Forest Lordfish`?

According to this [list](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/971712-fantasy-life/faqs/70542), the Forest Lordfish is considered a Boss Fish, and implies that is under the category of **rare fish**. This means that it will not spawn if you leave two screens away, as mentioned in this [thread](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189768/when-do-the-in-world-resources-respawn?rq=1).

So how can we counter this? 
Simply, it is different depending on the rare item being presented.

- Sometimes you will have to reset the area, by leaving/entering the area. This is usually the case.
- Other-times you may have to sleep for 1-3 days, but it is highly unlikely.

---

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/971712-fantasy-life/70260744)

Comment: I've been there and back a few times and a few in game days have passed, but no respawn. Do I have to show up again as an angler?

Comment: I would guess that there is a chance of randomness of the fish appearing.  I don't know for sure, but there feels like more randomness in what fish appear than other resources.  I've definitely had the Sacred Earth Tree and a similar tier mining spot respawn in 1-2 days.

Comment: There is a certain degree of randomness, but it looks like time is a factor for the respawns. The boss resources seems to like to take their sweet time to respawn.

Comment: Traveling around also seems to help.

Comment: The appearance of rare items/gatherables like boss fish/trees/rocks are also influenced by your character's luck stat.  Higher luck means these should appear more often.